# rails rspec http basic authentication test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

how do I test logging into a rails 3.1 app with http basic auth using rspec2 & capybara?

I'm using this;

```
 describe "GET 'index'" do
      it "should be successful" do
        request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
        get 'index'
        response.should be_success
      end
    end
```

but it gives me this error;

```
 NoMethodError:
            undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329985/http-basic-auth-for-capybara

Answer (score 17):

Capybara comes with [Rack::Test](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test) built in.

So, you can use the [`Rack::Test::Session.basic_authorize` method](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/blob/master/lib/rack/test.rb#L156-L166) to set the [Authorization HTTP header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8) before making a request.

```
basic_authorize 'username', 'password'
get 'index'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
```

This should be:

```
request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
```

as [request](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/AbstractRequest.html) is not an instance variable.

Comment: I'm using the solution here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768718/rails-rspec-make-tests-to-pass-with-http-basic-authentication