# send delete request to controller in cucumber step definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rspec, devise, cucumber

Does any of you know how to do (implement) something like this:

**sample.feature**

```
...
scenario: unauthorized user cannot delete event
  Given list of events
  When event is deleted
  Then nothing happen
...
```

**sample_steps.rb**

```
...
When /^event is deleted$/ do
  delete (_path_to_controller_ + "/%d" % @events.first().id)
...
```

Of course in this step I want to send a request according to the result of *rake routes*, which is something like this (I've moved resources under *admin* path):

**rake routes**

```
...
DELETE /admin/controller_name/:id(.:format)         controller_name#destroy
...
```

I have been experimenting and searching internet for so long and yet I don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Rack::Test](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test) in the past to send DELETE requests to an API:

```
When /^event is deleted$/ do
  header 'Accept', 'application/json'
  header 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

  authorize "username", "password"
  url = _path_to_controller_ + "/%d" % @events.first().id)

  delete url
end
```

Having said that, I'm not sure I'd recommend it in your case. Is the event going to be deleted from some action in the interface such as clicking a button? If so, you should use capybara to log in and click the button. This gives you the benefit of full integration coverage and you don't have to deal with Rack::Test (not that it's a bad tool, but it's another tool).

Comment: Thx, I just wanted to check if manual hacking is possible, despite capybara approach to click through all the links.

Comment: I've just tested it in opposite situation. I tried to delete event as admin and `delete` returned `Rack::MockResponse` with error: `{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}`, but I'm able to open pages via `visit` from _capybara_ what mean I'm logged in !?. I'm new to rails so probably I am missing something obvious ?

Comment: It's because the Rack::Test request is running in a separate process and requires its own user to be logged in. Did you add the authorize call?

Comment: Yes, I did... the problem was *gem devise* and it's default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Uff I've solved the problem.
Great Thanks to Beerlington

So in this post I will sum up my time with the problem and its solution.

**Related topics and documentation**

- [StackOverflow: HTTP basic auth for Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329985/http-basic-auth-for-capybara)
- [Devise: How To: Use HTTP Basic Authentication](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication)

**Background**

I'm using *devise gem* for authentication. My goal was to check if possible is manual hacking to resource management features like delete.

**Problem**

Above ;D

**Solution**

> ```
> When /^event is deleted$/ do
>   header 'Accept', 'application/json'
>   header 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
>
>   authorize "username", "password"
>   url = _path_to_controller_ + "/%d" % @events.first().id)
>
>   delete url
> end
> ```

is not working with default *devise* configuration. Because it uses HTTP authentication which is disabled by default.

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
# Tell if authentication through HTTP Basic Auth is enabled. False by default.
# It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
# given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:token]` will
# enable it only for token authentication.
# config.http_authenticatable = false
```

So if we want to make above test working, we need to change last line to:

```
config.http_authenticatable = true
```

But the question is do we really wanna do it ?

And as a last note: *header* calls are optional. Records are deleted with or without them.

- with them *delete* return with status code : *204 No Content*
- and without them *delete* return with status code : *302 Found*