# how to login basic authorization modal browser using Cucumber, Capybara and Ruby

Tags: ruby, authentication, cucumber, authorization, capybara

[image: example]

When I access the page, an authentication modal is displayed and I need to fill in this modal or authenticate in some way in order to proceed with the test.

I have tried solutions like:

```
Given /^I login as admin$/ do 
  if page.driver.respond_to?(:basic_auth)
    page.driver.basic_auth('username', 'password')

  elsif page.driver.respond_to?(:basic_authorize)
    page.driver.basic_authorize('username', 'password')

  elsif page.driver.respond_to?(:browser) && page.driver.browser.respond_to?(:basic_authorize)
    page.driver.browser.basic_authorize('username', 'password')

  else
    raise "I don't know how to log in!"
  end
end
```

but this error is returned:

```
Given I login as admin                # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:1
      undefined method `basic_auth' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x00007f7f1b97c628> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Is the modal that's coming up actually a system authroization box,  or is it just an HTML built modal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP basic auth for Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329985/http-basic-auth-for-capybara)

Comment: is a system authorization box